# ASP.NET MVC how to check if instance already exists before creating a new one

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

ASP.NET MVC how can I check if instance of a class already exists before creating a new one? Here is the class:

```
public class Doctor
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}
}
```

In the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Title,Id,FirstName,LastName,Address,Facility,IsAvailable")] Doctor doctor)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Doctors.Add(doctor);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(doctor);
    }
```

How can I check if the dcotor already exists, by comparing firstName and LastName? I think I need something like:

`var doctors = from d in db.Doctors select d;`

```
doctors = doctors.FirstOrDefault(d => d.FirstName == search && d.LAstName == searchlast); return RedirectToAction("Index", "Doctor");
```

Basically if the doctor already exists I do not want to be able to create a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to try to get the doctor with the input doctor's firstname and lastname from the database.

Which you can do by

```
var doc = doctors.FirstOrDefault(d => d.FirstName == doctor.FirstName && d.LastName == doctor.LastName);
```

And check if `doc` is null or not. If it is null that means the doctor with the specified firstname and lastname do not exist, and in that case a new doctor should be added to the database.

```
if (doc == null)
{
    db.Doctors.Add(doctor);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
else
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Doctor");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there

```
var doctor = doctors.FirstOrDefault(d => d.FirstName == search && d.LAstName == searchlast); 

if(doctor == default)
  //doctor not found - maybe add it?
else
  //doctor found - return it?
  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Doctor");
```

If you always want to return a doctor and only add it if it is not found, remove the else and assign a new doctor in the if. If your c# is older and doesn't understand the `default` keyword, use `null` instead

Answer (score 1):

first of all create a separate method for it helps you reuse it some day you wana create client validation too.

```
    private bool isDuplicateName(string fname,string lname)
    {
       return  db.Doctors.Any(d=>d.FirstName == fname and d.LastName == lname);
    }
```

then in your action just call it

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Title,Id,FirstName,LastName,Address,Facility,IsAvailable")] Doctor doctor)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(isDuplicateName(doctor.FirstName,doctor.LastName) == false)
                {
                    db.Doctors.Add(doctor);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }else{
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
               }
        }

        return View(doctor);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
    var doctorExist = db.Doctors.Where(d => d.FirstName == search && d.LastName == searchlast).Count() > 0;

    if(doctorExist){
      //doctor found
    }else{
      //doctor not found
    }
```

If it found more than 0 results then `doctorExist = true.`
Hope this helps.